# Applying Web.config Modifications Without STSAdm

Tags: web-config, spwebconfigmodification

I have a solution where I am including a **webconfig.Name.xml** modification file in the **CONFIG** mapped folder. The problem is, it is only applied if I add a post-build step of:

> stsadm -o copyappbincontent

Which is not desirable. I was wondering if there is any other way, other than **SPWebConfigModification**?

Any best practices for this kind of work?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the **[SPWebConfigModification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebConfigModification%28v=office.15%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)** without stsadm requirement.
here is the example:

Lets say you want to change mode value to Off.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
       <customErrors mode="On">
    <system.web>
 <configuration>
```

here is the code

```
private void SimpleSample()
 {
     // Get an instance of my local web application
     SPWebApplication webApp = new SPSite("http://localhost").WebApplication;
 
     // Create my new modification to set the mode attibute to "Off".
     // Example: <customErrors mode="Off">
     SPWebConfigModification modification = new SPWebConfigModification("mode", "system.web/customErrors");
     modification.Owner = "SimpleSampleUniqueOwnerValue";
     modification.Sequence = 0;
     modification.Type = SPWebConfigModification.SPWebConfigModificationType.EnsureAttribute;
     modification.Value = "Off";
     // Add my new web.config modification.
     webApp.WebConfigModifications.Add(modification);    
// Save web.config changes. 
     webApp.Update();
     // Applies the list of web.config modifications to all Web applications in this Web service across the farm.
     webApp.Farm.Services.GetValue<SPWebService>().ApplyWebConfigModifications
 }
```

read more over here: [How To: Modify the web.config file in SharePoint using SPWebConfigModification](https://web.archive.org/web/20101230014154/http://blog.crsw.com/2007/09/20/how-to-modify-the-web-config-file-in-sharepoint-using-spwebconfigmodification/)

[Managing Web.config Modifications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648376.aspx)

Comment: I explicitly said **other than SPWebConfigModification**

Comment: thing is you dont want stsadm, so that's why i mentioned the above...

Comment: same thing you can do via powershell http://blog.karstein-consulting.com/2010/09/02/add-web-config-modification-with-powershell-spwebconfigmodification/ otherwise you can do it manually